# Speech recognition too slow response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

After running below code it takes more than 3 minutes to print the statement which i said as input

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
audio=r.listen(source)
try:
print("You said:"+r.recognize_google(audio))
except Exception:
print("repeat again")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my internet is good, microphone is working then why it is taking too long?

Comment: Please indent your code. What you have now is an error.

Comment: But sir i dont know what is an error it is not showing any kind of error. I have 8gb Ram and 4gb graphic card is it due to hardware requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It can probably be your internet connection or your microphon, i work in a porject with speech recognition but the response sometimes it takes a little more than 10 seconds

Comment: my internet is good, microphone is working then why it is taking too long?

Answer (score 0):

This my exemple, i employed this a raspberry

```
import speech_recognition as sr
#import robby
r = sr.Recognizer()
def inicio():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Di algo:")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        funciones(audio)

def funciones(audio):
    try:
        print("Dijiste " + r.recognize_google(audio))
        if r.recognize_google(audio)=='hello':
            print('hello ')
            #robby.arranca()
            #inicio()
        elif r.recognize_google(audio)=='stop':
            robby.stop()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))



inicio()
```